# A server-side library to extract the content of web-pages

Tags: php, web, html-parsing, web-crawler

I'm looking for a server-side library (preferably in PHP) to parse and extract the content of web-pages that is free for commercial use. It should be able to extract the headline and html (including images) of the content part of a page, but filter out ads and irrelevant content.

The [Readability Parser API](http://www.readability.com/developers/api/parser) is a non-free software that does that, but I'm looking for free alternatives.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Visit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using [Boilerpipe](http://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/). It's for Java unfortunately, but if you won't find anything in PHP, it may be useful to you. It's not perfect, obviously, but it's worth a try. It's also open source, thus it's possible to make necessary changes.

It has several so-called 'extractors', so you can choose the one which suits your need the most.

Usage is also pretty straightforward, on example:

```
URL url = new URL("http://example.com/article");
String articleText = ArticleExtractor.INSTANCE.getText(url);
```

Comment: As far as I can see this library only extracts the textual content of the page. I'm looking for a solution that extracts all the relevant HTML (importantly, I need the images).

Comment: It turned out that you can get the images as well using boilerpipe (the source version had an imageExtractor class). I ended up using this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)
I used it to build a scraper for a rather complex website. Works very well.

Comment: I need the code to work with arbitrary web-pages. The problem is how to filter out the non-content part of the page in a generic way.

Comment: you need to view the target webpage source. Try to figure out what <element> or specific id or class of the page you want. Scrape away based on that particular part of the page. Even if they don't have any class or id attributes, you can still call it by referring to it in a bread-crumb way e.g. div > span > p > h1

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get any data from page, like the geographic position of the Eiffel Tower from Wikipedia, is jQuery DOM.

```
<span class="geo-dms">
    <span class="geo-lat">48°51′29″</span>
    <span class="geo-lon">2°17′40″</span>
</span>
```

Test in FireBug console `jQuery('.geo-lat').text()`. jQuery is a JavaScript library and the best result you get with server-side JavaScript web-server [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js). There is a lot of good Node.js solutions for web crawling with DOM traversing.